# add assembly from resources with ResourceManager

Tags: c#, resources, codedom

I would like to add an assembly with ResourceManager I have this code but it obviously doesn't work. Please help!

Loading the resource and trying to use it as an assembly:

```
  static ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("res", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

  static void Main()
  {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
  }

  static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
  {
     AppDomain domain = (AppDomain)sender;
     if(args.Name.Contains("System.Data.SQLite"))
     {
        return domain.Load(resourceManager.GetObject("System.Data.SQLite"));
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Putting the resource in a ResourceManager:

```
        using (ResourceWriter w = new ResourceWriter("res.resources"))
        {
           w.AddResource("System.Data.SQLite", File.ReadAllText("System.Data.SQLite.dll"));
        }

        if (CodeDom.Compile(outputValueTb.Text, Properties.Resources.src, iconValueTb.Text, "res.resources"))
        {
           //File.Copy("System.Data.SQLite.dll", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(outputValueTb.Text) + "/System.Data.SQLite.dll");
           File.Delete("res.resources");
           success("Built");
        }
```

### Edit

So I changed my code to this

```
w.AddResource("System.Data.SQLite", File.ReadAllBytes("System.Data.SQLite.dll"));
```

But I still don't know how to use the resource into an assembly with this code:

```
     AppDomain domain = (AppDomain)sender;
     if(args.Name.Contains("System.Data.SQLite"))
     {
        return domain.Load(resourceManager.GetObject("System.Data.SQLite")); //should be a resource not bytes[] 
     }
     return null;
```

Comment: Why do you read a binary file with **File.ReadAllText**? A DLL is not a text file. Use **File.ReadAllBytes** instead (and adapt your code so it handles the returned byte array)

Comment: How "and adapt your code so it handles the returned byte array"

Comment: What do you mean with your question "How"? You mean, you don't know how to add a byte array resource to your resource file?

Comment: I don't know how to handle the returned byte array

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific of what your problem would be regarding byte arrays (and resources)

Comment: Ok i'll edit my question

Comment: Erm... your comment in the code "//should be a resource not bytes[]". Since when is AppDomain.Load expecting a resource as argument?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45506/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-sanchixx)

Comment: It expects bytes[]? I'm really sorry for being such a newb

Comment: `cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Reflection.AssemblyName'` Do I have to cast or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the dll as a project item file and marked it "Embedded Resource" on the Build Action type (under properties), then you can use the following. Resolver is the event handler that you already have. Note: I haven't checked syntax, just typed it here; so fix syntax if needed.

```
internal static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
   var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                 .GetManifestResourceNames()
                 .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Contains("System.Data.SQLite"));

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && args.Name.Contains("SQLite")) 
   {
    using(var strm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name))
    {
      var bytes = new byte[strm.Length];
      stream.Read(bytes, 0, strm.Length);
      return Assembly.Load(bytes);
    }   
   }
   return null;
}
```